# How can I use an .ico as an IconSource within Prism?

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, mvvm, icons

I am assigning a path to an IconSource property binding in the ViewModel which references a .ico file, however this exception is thrown on Prism's `RaisePropertyChanged()` call:

> Argument 'picture' must be a picture that can be used as a Icon.

From what I understand a .ico is a type of picture file. Also in the constructor of the ViewModel I am assigning another .ico file by default and that loads fine, it is only on the second call in which I get this exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you checked the picture size of the icon? It should also be able to support high DPI display, and it has to be in PNG format.

In this [concise short tutorial](http://www.axialis.com/tutorials/tutorial-vistaicons.html), supported size and colors are:

256x256 - RGB/A 64x64 - RGB/A 48x48 - RGB/A 32x32 - RGB/A 24x24 - RGB/A 16x16 - RGB/A 
256x256 - 256c 64x64 - 256c 48x48 - 256c 32x32 - 256c 24x24 - 256c 16x16 - 256c 
256x256 - 16c 64x64 - 16c 48x48 - 16c 32x32 - 16c 24x24 - 16c 16x16 - 16c

Whereas 256c means 256 colors, 16c means 16 colors, RGB/A means 24-bit colors with 8 bits alpha.

Another note in the above tutorial is:

> The PNG compression is embedded in the ICO file for the 256x256 images
>   only. PNG compressed Windows Vista™ icons cannot be read and edited
>   with an Windows® XP-only compatible icon editor, nor can you open them
>   with a PNG image editor.

But unfortunately, WPF icons is more toward Vista and above, including Windows 7. I suggest you follow common guidelines for Icons for Windows Vista and Windows 7, instead of going backward with Windows XP.

Comment: My icons are of valid size, the only issue is they are of .ico type. Also sometimes they work and sometimes they throw that exception. Maybe if I use .png format they will be consistently loaded without exceptions? Also they are always loaded on the systray as an icon but for some odd reason they throw that exception after loading.

Comment: If you're using Windows XP, there's a slight chance your PNG icons will throw an exception if it's opened in Windows XP.